# react-rails in production can not create new object

Tags: ruby-on-rails, reactjs

I have an application which has `react-rails` gem . Everything works perfectly in `development` but when I deployed it to `Ubuntu server 18.04` , everything works fine, but there is a mysterious behaviour which is : 
Sometimes when I try to create object it can be done sometimes without any error `app` does not create object. 
There is no error in any where. 
Everything else in app in production work very well. any help?

Comment: What do the application logs say for this request? Can you create objects from rails console?

Comment: In `production.log` , there is nothing about it, the `create` request just ignores , but I was able to perform `seed` to populate the `database`  without any error. As I said , the app creates object by itself , but not always

Comment: I can create object from `console` as well. I think sometimes there is no request to `server` by submitting form, but I do not know why?